# How to plot age distribution with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have Data Frame, which contains 2 columns: age and gender.

```
sex,age
1,30
2,29
1,34
1,27
2,28
2,28
1,40
1,30
1,27
2,31
1,37
1,31
2,28
2,30
2,27
2,27
2,29
2,32
1,28
1,27
1,28
1,28
1,29
1,33
1,32
1,30
```

How can I plot age distribution for each gender?

Comment: You mean `df.groupby('sex').plot()`? or `df.groupby('sex').hist()` Also the norm here is to post text rather than images, ideally raw data and code

Comment: Please add code version of data frame (not a PNG file) so no one needs to type it, just to help ... and if you provide what you had as best try to achieve this with pandas, other coders might be more motivated to show where to change or what to do differently. Thanks.

Comment: @EdChum looks like data_frame.groupby('sex').hist() is the right thing. However it render multiple plots. How can I draw all distributions exactly on 1 plot?

Comment: how about `df.groupby('sex')['age'].hist()`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`groupby` then `plot` with `kind='kde'`

```
df1.groupby('sex').age.plot(kind='kde')
```

[image]

Per @EdChum

```
df1.groupby('sex').age.hist()
```

[image]